# Adding user ip to existing meta_value with single meta_id as array

Tags: mysql, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I am currently getting the user IP on a slider change and sending it to the WP DB but I want to keep the DB smaller and have a single meta_id for the list of IPs.

My current code is sort of working but as it adds the new ip to the existing array something is causing it to turn into a multidimensional one and breaking it.

Here is my code.

```
$user_ip = $_POST['ip'];
    $user_score = $_POST['sliderValue'];
    $postID =  $_POST['post_id'];

    $currentIPs =  maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta( $postID, 'user_ip'));

    $currentIPs[] = $user_ip;


    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {

              update_post_meta($postID, 'user_ip', $currentIPs);

            echo var_dump($currentIPs);


    }
   die();
}
```

I have tried with add_post_meta and that works fine but it creates a new meta_id for each IP which would just make the database huge. For performance and space saving I was just one key and ID with all the values.

Comment: Do you mean by storing all the ips in single meta feild? with same id?

Comment: Hi,

Yeah I would like to store the IDs in a single meta_field with the same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is programmed to create a new meta_id every time you use update_meta_data.
However the workaround is that you can store the IPS within same meta_id by seperating IPS with commas.

Replace

```
 $currentIPs   =  maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta( $postID, 'user_ip'));
 $currentIPs[] = $user_ip;
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
 update_post_meta($postID, 'user_ip', $currentIPs);
```

With

```
$currentIPs = $user_ip;
$userIp = get_post_meta($postID, 'user_ip',true);
 if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
if (empty($userIp)) {
   update_post_meta($postID, 'user_ip', $currentIPs);
} else {
   $newvalue = $currentIPs .','. $userIp;
   update_post_meta($postID, 'user_ip', $newvalue);
}
```

Later if you want these data in an array, you can use php's `explode()` function afterwards

Comment: This is sort of working but instead of adding the previous IPS it is adding ARRAY and then the next ip.

If you then add another, it will be ARRAY, ARRAY, the new ip

Comment: It is working! Can you explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Actually you were trying to store it as an array, which was not very much feasible.
 What i did was removed those array things and stored the value as strings

Comment: Ah I see! If I wanted to put a check on what you have done to make sure not to add the same id to the list, would I need to explode it and then check before running your code?

Comment: I answered my own question. $allIPs   = get_post_meta( $postID, 'user_ip');
        $list_ips = explode(',',$allIPs[0]);
       if(!in_array($user_ip, $list_ips )) {}

Comment: A hack maybe, stripping spaces?. `str_replace(' ', '', $newvalue)`